# Image in ListView not completely centered

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm trying to display a list of images in a ListView. I'd like these images to be displayed in the center of the "item".

I've tried to achieve this by setting the respective VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment to center. This does not give me the result I want. When an item is selected, you can clearly see a larger "blue" area on the left.

Am I missing something?

GUI example:
[image: Image not in center example]

My code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyClass.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Name="lvImages" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  ItemHeight="100" ItemWidth="100"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Image Source="{Binding Bitmap}" Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Button  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">Picture details</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">Document options</Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">Go go go area</Button>
  </Grid>
</window>
```

PS: Sorry for stealing your cookies! OMNOMNOMNOM!!!

Answer (score 0):

there have two ways
1.set ActualWidth of GridViewColumn
 and you have to add a border

```
        <ListView.View>

            <GridView >

                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"   Width="200" x:Name="column">

                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=column}"/>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="GetRes"  Width="120" x:Name="sss">

                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Border  MinWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=sss}">

                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsReceive}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                            </Border>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```

2.set style

```
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>

    </Style>
```